# Android - CoordinatorLayout, (CircleImageView inside AppBarLayout)

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I try to create a collapsing layout on scroll, but I encounter an issue with my avatar, indeed when the CircleImageView is inside my AppBarLayout, nothing happens, I need to put it below my ToolbarLayout, here is my xml to be clearer :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_layout_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/circle_image_view_avatar"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_size_avatar"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_size_avatar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_margin_top_avatar"
                    android:src="@drawable/avatar_6"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                    app:civ_border_width="@dimen/avatar_border_width"
                    app:finalHeight="@dimen/image_final_width"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_behavior="com.example.AvatarImageBehavior"
                    app:startHeight="2dp"
                    app:startToolbarPosition="2dp"
                    app:startXPosition="2dp" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame_layout_ranking"
                    android:layout_width="47dp"
                    android:layout_height="47dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/circle_image_view_avatar"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/circle_image_view_avatar"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/circle_image_view_avatar">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_button_ranking_trophies_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_button_ranking_trophies_size"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_white"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_classement" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame_layout_trophies"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/circle_image_view_avatar"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/circle_image_view_avatar"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/circle_image_view_avatar">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_button_ranking_trophies_size"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_button_ranking_trophies_size"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_white"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_trophees" />

                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame_layout_level"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/circle_image_view_avatar"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/circle_image_view_level"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_size_level"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_size_level"
                        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                        app:civ_border_width="@dimen/avatar_border_width" />

                </FrameLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_pseudo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/frame_layout_level"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_32" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <!-- Content -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
                ....
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>




    <!-- Final toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:background="#5025A5FF"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/text_view_pseudo"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_vertical"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:title="">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="Pseudo"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_18" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the code of my AvatarImageBehavior class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.R;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class AvatarImageBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<CircleImageView> {
    private final static float MIN_AVATAR_PERCENTAGE_SIZE   = 0.3f;
    private final static int EXTRA_FINAL_AVATAR_PADDING     = 80;

    private final static String TAG = "behavior";
    private Context mContext;

    private float mCustomFinalXPosition;
    private float mCustomFinalYPosition;
    private float mCustomStartXPosition;
    private float mCustomStartToolbarPosition;
    private float mCustomStartHeight;
    private float mCustomFinalHeight;

    private float mAvatarMaxSize;
    private float mFinalLeftAvatarPadding;
    private float mStartPosition;
    private int mStartXPosition;
    private float mStartToolbarPosition;
    private int mStartYPosition;
    private int mFinalYPosition;
    private int mStartHeight;
    private int mFinalXPosition;
    private float mChangeBehaviorPoint;

    public AvatarImageBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        mContext = context;

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AvatarImageBehavior);
            mCustomStartXPosition = a.getDimension(R.styleable.AvatarImageBehavior_startXPosition, 0);
            mCustomStartToolbarPosition = a.getDimension(R.styleable.AvatarImageBehavior_startToolbarPosition, 0);
            mCustomStartHeight = a.getDimension(R.styleable.AvatarImageBehavior_startHeight, 0);
            mCustomFinalHeight = a.getDimension(R.styleable.AvatarImageBehavior_finalHeight, 0);

            a.recycle();
        }

        init();

        mFinalLeftAvatarPadding = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_vertical_little_margin);
    }

    private void init() {
        bindDimensions();
    }

    private void bindDimensions() {
        mAvatarMaxSize = mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.game_answer_bonus);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, CircleImageView child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof Toolbar;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, CircleImageView child, View dependency) {
        maybeInitProperties(child, dependency);

        final int maxScrollDistance = (int) (mStartToolbarPosition);
        float expandedPercentageFactor = dependency.getY() / maxScrollDistance;

        if (expandedPercentageFactor < mChangeBehaviorPoint) {
            float heightFactor = (mChangeBehaviorPoint - expandedPercentageFactor) / mChangeBehaviorPoint;

            float distanceXToSubtract = ((mStartXPosition - mFinalXPosition) * heightFactor) + (child.getHeight()/2);
            float distanceYToSubtract = ((mStartYPosition - mFinalYPosition) * (1f - expandedPercentageFactor)) + (child.getHeight()/2);

            child.setX(mStartXPosition - distanceXToSubtract);
            child.setY(mStartYPosition - distanceYToSubtract);

            float heightToSubtract = ((mStartHeight - mCustomFinalHeight) * heightFactor);

            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = (int) (mStartHeight - heightToSubtract);
            lp.height = (int) (mStartHeight - heightToSubtract);
            child.setLayoutParams(lp);
        } else {
            float distanceYToSubtract = ((mStartYPosition - mFinalYPosition) * (1f - expandedPercentageFactor)) + (mStartHeight/2);

            child.setX(mStartXPosition - child.getWidth()/2);
            child.setY(mStartYPosition - distanceYToSubtract);

            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = (int) (mStartHeight);
            lp.height = (int) (mStartHeight);
            child.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void maybeInitProperties(CircleImageView child, View dependency) {
        if (mStartYPosition == 0) {
            // mStartYPosition = (int) (dependency.getY());
            mStartYPosition = 185;
        }

        if (mFinalYPosition == 0)
            mFinalYPosition = (dependency.getHeight() /2);

        if (mStartHeight == 0)
            mStartHeight = child.getHeight();

        if (mStartXPosition == 0)
            mStartXPosition = (int) (child.getX() + (child.getWidth() / 2));

        if (mFinalXPosition == 0) {
            // mFinalXPosition = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.abc_action_bar_content_inset_material) + ((int) mCustomFinalHeight / 2);
            mFinalXPosition = (int) (dependency.getWidth() - mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_final_width) + mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.profile_toolbar_margin_right));
        }

        if (mStartToolbarPosition == 0)
            mStartToolbarPosition = dependency.getY();

        if (mChangeBehaviorPoint == 0) {
            mChangeBehaviorPoint = (child.getHeight() - mCustomFinalHeight) / (2f * (mStartYPosition - mFinalYPosition));
        }
    }

    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");

        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Do you see why, my CircleImageView react only when it's outside the AppBarLayout. I need it to be inside because, my FrameLayout are views over the CircleImageView (an avatar). I begin with CoordinatorLayout so maybe I miss something.
Regards.